# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть такая функция, когда запускаю проект и вызываю эту функцию иногда вывает такую ошибку

**Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown**

на сервере достаточно ресурсов чтоб взять большую количество записей
в данный момент в таблице 3 миллиона записей
**как можно решить эту проблему?**

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ASPxGridView1.Visible = true;
            exportXls.Visible = true;
            var conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            var dt = new DataTable("SENDCLIENT");

            DateTime dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewStartDate.Value).Date;
            DateTime dateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewEndDate.Value).Date;
    
            cmd.CommandText = "GSB.clienta";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();


            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_date_from", dateStart);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_date_to", dateEnd);

            var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            Session["SENDCLIENT"] = dt;
            ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

**это function GSB.clienta**

```
create or replace function GSB.clienta(p_date_from in date, p_date_to in date) return sys_refcursor is
  rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open rc for
  select
       t.account,
       t.pname,
       t.COMMENTS,
       t.HRCODE
  from sent_client_acc t
 where trunc(t.insert_date) between p_date_from and p_date_to + 1;
  return(rc);
end GSB.clienta;
```

Comment: Это WinForms или всё-таки WebForms?

Comment: Судя по названию `ASPxGridView` - это проект типа Web Forms. Как он запускается? В IIS? Возможно, лимиты памяти заданы в IIS. Возможно, используется 32-битный IIS (переходите на 64-битный). Чем больше информации приведёте в вопросе, тем точнее и быстрее получите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соберите приложение под x64 для начала (не Any CPU), должно помочь.

И не совсем понятно, зачем высасывать из базы всю таблицу целиком в оперативку? Достаточно памяти - это сколько?

Еще вы полностью проигнорировали тот факт, что у вас используются `IDisposable` объекты - [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

```cs
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ASPxGridView1.Visible = true;
        exportXls.Visible = true;

        // IDisposable
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            DateTime dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewStartDate.Value).Date;
            DateTime dateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewEndDate.Value).Date;
    
            cmd.CommandText = "GSB.clienta";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_date_from", dateStart);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_date_to", dateEnd);

            var dt = new DataTable("SENDCLIENT");

            // IDisposable
            using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            } 
        }
        Session["SENDCLIENT"] = dt;
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

И еще вот это

> OracleDataAdapter has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260

Если ничего из выше показанного не помогло, попробуйте вот [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element).

Comment: Достаточно памяти - это 19gb